# convert amount form one currency to another currency in magento 2

Tags: magento2, currency

I need to convert amount from one currency to another currency in magento 2 not from store base currency

```
$priceCurrencyObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface'); //instance of PriceCurrencyInterface


$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); //get current store id if store id not get passed

$rate = $priceCurrencyObject->convert($USDamount, $store, 'INR');
```

I tried above code it will convert base currency to another currency.

My criteria is I need to mention from currency and to currency.

Is it possible in magento2

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code (or whole class) to convert from the one currency to another:

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: siarhey
 * Date: 8/26/17
 * Time: 7:25 AM
 */
class ConvertCurrencyTest
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory
     */
    protected $currencyFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
    ){
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Converts the amount value from one currency to another.
     * If the $currencyCodeFrom is not specified the current currency will be used.
     * If the $currencyCodeTo is not specified the base currency will be used.
     * 
     * @param float $amountValue like 13.54
     * @param string|null $currencyCodeFrom like 'USD'
     * @param string|null $currencyCodeTo like 'BYN'
     * @return float
     */
    public function convert($amountValue, $currencyCodeFrom = null, $currencyCodeTo = null)
    {
        /**
         * If is not specified the currency code from which we want to convert - use current currency
         */
        if (!$currencyCodeFrom) {
            $currencyCodeFrom = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
        }

        /**
         * If is not specified the currency code to which we want to convert - use base currency
         */
        if (!$currencyCodeTo) {
            $currencyCodeTo = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode();
        }

        /**
         * Do not convert if currency is same
         */
        if ($currencyCodeFrom == $currencyCodeTo) {
            return $amountValue;
        }

        /** @var float $rate */
        // Get rate
        $rate = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCodeFrom)->getAnyRate($currencyCodeTo);
        // Get amount in new currency
        $amountValue = $amountValue * $rate;

        return $amountValue;
    }
}
```

**Additional**, if you do not specify the currency from which you want to conver - current currency will be used. If you do not specify the currency in which you want to convert - base currency will be used.